# Best way to execute procedure with JPA StoredProcedureQuery in a for loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, jpa

What is the best way of executing a procedure inside a for loop?

This is what i have (this "for" is going to be slightly different in a future, but it's basically the same):

```
for(int i=0; i<300; i++){
     StoredProcedureQuery query = 
      this.entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("testProcedure");
     
     query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
     query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
     query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
 
     query.setParameter(1, "DF");
     query.setParameter(2, i);
     query.setParameter(3, "F");
     
     query.execute();
}
```

Is this recommendable or not? I need to do this for a proyect which need to execute a SP iterating through a list (which is a select to a table and has multiple records).

I tried doing this declarating a cursor with the select in a Query (native query) and iterate over it, but for some reason the sp was not getting executed, something like this:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cur IS select s_number from testTable where s_number in ( “some numbers (List)”);
    BEGIN
        FOR c IN cur LOOP
            testProcedure('DF', c.s_number, 'F');
        END LOOP;
        commit;
END;
```

And i can't make a SP in the DB with this cursor because we need to migrate this execution to Java.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can execute the stored procedure as a batch, but you need to do this in plain jdbc:

```
Connection con = this.entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).connection();
CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{ call testProcedure(?,?,?) }");

for(int i=0; i<300; i++){      
    stmt.setString(1, "DF");
    stmt.setInt(2, i);  
    stmt.setString(3, "F");  
    stmt.addBatch();
}

int [] updatesCount = stmt.executeBatch(); 
// Verify if all updatesCount is >= 0
```

But why not to do this in a procedure in database? If you need to put messages in a queue (example) after the process is executed, you can make the stored procedure fill a temporary table with the results for make it possible to do this in your java code.

Comment: Thank for this! Doing it this way improved the performance of the execution.

Comment: And i can't put this execution in a procedure due the migration of this execution to Java (doing this in a procedure was my first thought, but it's a decision that is out of my reach).